# How to solve the error while adding a support library

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library

I am trying to add a support library for notification project for the first time .But getting some error

```
> Error:Execution failed for task
> ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>     com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
> org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
> 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin\java.exe'' finished with
> non-zero exit value 2
```

don't know how to solve, hope some one give a hint.
My build Gradel

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.union.noti"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Error when adding multidex I am getting now

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/annotation/LayoutRes.class
```

Comment: Try adding " multiDexEnabled true" in your Gradle's defaultConfig and the compile and run

Comment: clean and rebuild the project

Comment: getting error asError:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/annotation/LayoutRes.class

Comment: duplicate entry means that you are have two files with same name in your case which is "LayoutRes.class"

Comment: @NeelaySrivastava Post your `build.gradle`

Comment: @NeelaySrivastava Did you solve yet ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why are you putting android-support-v4.jar in libs folder. if you want to use android-support-v4.jar library uee like this :

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

in some where in your project support library and design library or appcompat library is conflicting. because support library also have the appcompat library in it. use like this may this help you. let me know if not success.

Comment: I just copied a jar file in the libs folder thats the error thx every one

Answer (score 0):

try to put this into Build.gradle(Module:app) in android section

```
defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

if its not working than just try with restart the android studio.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Do this in your root Gradle file

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xxxxx"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Comment: On adding multiDexEnabled true  I am getting error as::Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/annotation/LayoutRes.class

Comment: add your Gradle to your question

Answer (score 0):

You need To add **Multidexing** in Your **Gradle File** like see in the **Image**.. and please Update your **gardle with Highlighted Part**

[image]

**check the highlighted part paste it like this**
[image]

Comment: Still getting error Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/annotation/LayoutRes.class

Comment: @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }  you need to update this code in your LayoutRes.class

Comment: LayoutRes is part of the Android support library. It was not created in the project. Please refer to my answer for the reason it's duplicated

Comment: please see in the second image

Comment: Ya and thx it is solved I just copied the jar file in the libs folder thats the error

Comment: what happen you tick right as favourite answer and again untick??

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to the other answers, you don't need multidex enabled.

You are compiling the v4 library twice... Remove the `compile files` line because that's already handled by `compile fileTree` which says to compile all jar files in the lib directory. Therefore, you don't need to add additional lines unless the jar files are outside the lib directory.

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
//... 
compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
```

Anyways, why aren't you just compiling the v4 library with Gradle?

```
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1"
```